# ErrorAccessDenied on https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Trying to use the **ms graph api** and keep getting this error on selected endpoints including `v1.0/me/messages`.

Looks like a simple issue with privileges *(unsure why user would not have privilege to access own emails??)*, but what is confusing me is that when I sign on with the same *Office365 credentials* and access the same endpoint on `developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer` it works OK.

Not an authentication token issue as exact same request to `v1.0/me` endpoint works fine.

Debugging using curl from server :

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0e.....dRcgg"   
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

I get a good result, same request to `/v1.0/me/messages` endpoint results in :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "019d61ff-77fd-4e9f-a94e-38faf741ac33",
      "date": "2017-04-02T00:04:16"
    }
  }
}
```

To repeat, the issue that is throwing me is that I am able to access this endpoint successfully with the same credentials from `developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer`

Answer (score 2):

OK, have resolved the issue so posting here for the benefit of anyone else with the same issue.

It is all about the scope requested on the authentication request.  Had copied a code sample and it was only requesting scope:-

scope: 'User.Read Mail.Send offline_access'

Hence the Access Denied when I went outside this scope.....rookie error!

Comment: I know it's been a while, but how did you specify the scope to use? ALl i'm using is `xhr.open('GET', 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts', true);` and seeing the same issue.